# Mongoose - Cannot find module './models/Question'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to get a hang of Mongoose, but having some troubles. I've implemented my models like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    var QuestionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      author: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Author is required']
      },
      headline: String,
      description: String,
      answers: [
        { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: 'Answer'
        }
      ],
      createdAt: { 
        type: Date, 
        default: Date.now 
      }
    }, {timestamps: true});

    module.exports = mongoose.model('Question', QuestionSchema);
```

I try to require it in app.js:

```
const Question = require('./models/Question');
```

But I get `Error: Cannot find module './models/Question'` when trying to run `node app.js`.

Any ideas on why I'm getting this?

Comment: Is your model file named `Question.js` and residing in `models` folder relative to the file you are trying to include it into?

Comment: Yea to the forlder, but it is named Question.ts

Comment: Node.js won't find a .ts file.  You're not using typescript; why use the .ts extension?

Comment: Get an idea from here https://github.com/shivamkrpandey/accounts-stoverflow I have created a repo to solve one issue earlier. Hope this will help you to understand.

Comment: rename your file as Question.js

Comment: Oh I see, my previous model was at .ts-file... Thanks!